# Can't get example in Grails 2.4.4 documentation to work. (Extending RestfulController super class)

Tags: grails, groovy

I've been trying to implement [this](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.4/guide/webServices.html#extendingRestfulController) example in the Grails 2.4.4 documentation but I can't seem to get the source code to compile.

The code I am having a problem with is:

```
@Override
protected Score queryForResource(Serializable id) {
    Score.where {
        id == id && Game.id = params.GameId  //Error
    }.find()
}
```

The IDE warns of an error at line marked with error in the above code. The IDE error is:

```
((id == id) && Game.id) is a binary expression, but it should be a variable expression at line: 16 column: 33.
```

The compiler error is:

```
  [groovyc] org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
  [groovyc] C:\Users\PC_2\Documents\Grails\WS\grails-app\controllers\ws\ScoreController.groovy: 16: 
  [groovyc] ((id == id) && Game.id) is a binary expression, but it should be a variable expression at line: 16 column: 33. File: C:\Users\PC_2\Documents\Grails\WS\grails-app\controllers\ws\ScoreController.groovy @ line 16, column 33.
  [groovyc]                id == id && Game.id = params.authorId
  [groovyc]                                    ^
  [groovyc] 
  [groovyc] 1 error
```

If additional information is needed to resolve the problem, I'll do my best to provide it. Thanks!

Comment: `Game.id = params.GameId` should be `Game.id == params.GameId`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That fixed the syntax error but I now have another problem. By any chance do you know why I'm getting <Cannot query property "params" - no such property on class ws.Score exists.>? It doesn't seem to have been defined in the example in the documentation

Comment: You cannot refer `params` inside `where` query. assign it to a different variable just outside where query and use the variable instead.

Comment: Thanks you to for the help, I got the application to work.